# Using pam_exec.so for openvpn authentication

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, openvpn, pam

I've set up a PAM authentication config for OpenVPN.

```
auth required pam_exec.so debug expose_authtok /opt/openvpn/bin/pamauth
```

The script `pamauth` returns `0` on success. I verify this is true by also echoing the value to a file from the `pamauth` script.

```
<user authentication process>
echo $EXIT_CODE >/tmp/result       #yields a '0' in /tmp/result
exit $EXIT_CODE
```

But authentication fails, and the **`auth.log`** shows the following, though I can clearly see from `/tmp/result` that my `pamauth` script ran and called `exit 0`

```
Jul  5 09:53:29 client openvpn: pam_exec(openvpn:auth): send password to child
Jul  5 09:53:29 client openvpn: pam_exec(openvpn:auth): Calling /opt/openvpn/bin/pamauth ...
Jul  5 09:53:29 client openvpn: pam_unix(openvpn:account): could not identify user (from getpwnam(test40))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message doesn't even *mention* `pam_exec`.

```
Jul  5 09:53:29 client openvpn: pam_unix(openvpn:account): could not identify user (from getpwnam(test40))
```

The problem is in the account management (`account`) stage. (If the config for `pam.d/openvpn` doesn't have any `account` modules, PAM will use the ones configured in `pam.d/other`.)

"Could not identify user" here means the `pam_unix` module **could not find the user account `test40` in the system.** If you have recently edited `nsswitch.conf`, you might have to restart OpenVPN.